# How to pull a Docker image in Github actions for a compute engine VM?

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, github-actions

Using GH actions I'm building and pushing an image to my docker repository. How can this be pulled on a Google compute engine after having completed `setup-gcloud`:

```
      steps:
      - name: setup gcloud
        uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          version: '290.0.1'
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
```

I am aware of [GCE-Github actions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/tree/master/example-workflows/gce) and the google/docker-registry. But as my VM is not [container-optimized](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance) I want to run

`docker pull [docker-hub-repo]` and perform a `docker-compose up` in a specific dir afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realise that the obvious [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) command is sufficient for this.

`- run: gcloud compute ssh --zone $GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE $GCE_INSTANCE --command 'docker login -u [user] -p [password] && docker pull [repository:tag]'`

**2022 Edit**

For better safety, use [*Github Secrets*](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets).
To avoid direct use of the SSH command via `run`, there is a job `appleboy/ssh-action@master` for this;

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:

    #Job starts here
    - name: executing remote ssh commands
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.WEBSPACE_HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.WEBSPACE_USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.WEBSPACE_PASS }}

        #Bash commands may be placed line by line here
        script: |
          cd ...
          git pull
          docker-compose up --build --detach
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [install Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) on several Linux Platforms and on macOS and Windows10 through Docker Desktop.

The command "docker pull" pulls image by default from Docker Hub. You could also pull the images from your [desired repository](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry) by specifying the path of repository.

You need to [install Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) so that you could run the command "[docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)" which starts compose and runs your entire app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware how this stuff works - the thing I was looking for was just to obvious. See my solution.
But it probably would be better to run this on an container optimized GCE for full gcloud sdk support.